# Angular component doesn't update view as expected

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-components, angular-template, angular-changedetection

I have a "small" problem with a component that doesn't update itself as expected. There is a component that provides a `publish` function. This function calls `generateDownload` with a list of objects. Now the `getDrawing` is called. The data returned by `sscmData.getDrawing` updates the view and it works like a charm.

```js
export class DrawingComponent  {
    ...

    getDrawing(distance: DistanceSplit, reloadPredrawSkaters?: boolean): Observable<any> {

        return this.sscmData.getDrawing(distance.ID, distance.distance).pipe(
            map((response: Drawing) => {
                    ...
                    do some things
                    ...
            })
        )
    }

    publish(distances: DistanceSplit[]) {
        this.generateDownload(distances).subscribe(tabledata => {
            console.log(tabledata)
        })
    }

    generateDownload(list: DistanceSplit[]): Observable<any> {
        return from(list).pipe(
            concatMap((distance: DistanceSplit, index: number) => {
                return this.getDrawing(distance).pipe(
                    tap(() => {
                        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
                        console.log(this.propress);
                        this.propress++;
                    }),
                    map(res => {
                        let tabledata = ...
                        return tabledata;
                    })
                );
            })
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is `propress`, It is a simple variable and I want to see in the component view the current value `{{ propress }}`.
But the value is only shown when the observable is processed, completely. So it allways shows the length of the list, but not the current value.

I expexcted to see an increasing value, e.g. 1...2...3...4... etc. How can I get it to work?

Comment: I've reproduced your code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-propress?file=src/app/hello.component.ts and it works as you've described. BTW you don't need to call `detectChanges` unless you're using onPush change detection and even if you are there's better ways of doing it.

Comment: @wlf the `detectChanges`was just a desperated try to get it to work... The code looks exactly as mine but in my environment it wont work :-(

Comment: In yours if you submit an array of 4 distances, will the propress number go straight to 4? Then if you give an array of 3 distances it jumps to 7? What is the console.log inside the `tap` outputting? sequential numbers or jumping like the value in the html?

Comment: @wlf the console output shows sequential numbers

Comment: It's possible the responses are coming back so quickly you don't see the intermediate numbers in the html. Try adding the `delay` in `getDrawing` as in the stackblitz to check this.

Comment: @wlf the `delay` give the solution. Without a `delay` the view jumps from 0 to the end. Furthermore I was using `mergeMap` instead of `concatMap` as you do. Now it seems to work :-) Thx so much!

Comment: @wlf the `delay` can also be set to `0` but it has to be set... strange